# Get the difference between dataframes according to specific columns pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple big dataframes and I need to get the difference between them, according to specific columns, while keeping the data of the other columns.
for example, if I have 2 dataframes as below.

df1:

```
   num    Ref   Alt    DP     NL
0  300     C     A    50.0   30.0  
1  500     C     A    45.0   90.0 
2  255     A     C    69.0   26.0
3  450     B     B    55.0   25.0
```

df2:

```
   num    Ref   Alt    DP     NL
0  300     C     A    71.0   88.0  
1  500     A     A    45.0   54.0   
2  255     A     A    55.0   55.0
3  450     B     B    70.0   15.0
```

I'd like to get the difference between those dataframes according to specific columns ['num','Ref','Alt'] while keeping the data form the remaining columns ['DP', 'NL'].
In the example, rows 0 and 3 are the same across the 2 dataframes (since ['num','Ref','Alt'] are the same), so the output dataframes should look something like that:

df1:

```
   num    Ref   Alt     DP     NL
0  500     C     A     45.0   90.0   
2  255     A     C     69.0   26.0
```

df2:

```
   num    Ref   Alt    DP     NL
1  500     A     A    45.0   54.0   
2  255     A     A    55.0   55.0
```

or get it in the same dataframe, if possible...

I've tried to think of few solutions,one is concatenating them and then remove the duplicates, but beacuse they are bif dataframes, it might cause problems,or looping through the dataframes and use the below script:

```
temp_df = df_list[0]

for df in df_list[1:]:

    df_filtered_for_diff = pd.merge(temp_df, df, on=['num', 'Ref', 'Alt'], how='outer')                                                

    temp_df = df_filtered_for_diff

return (temp_df)
```

but I was wondering if there are better solutions?

Comment: I got lost here: `In the example, rows 0 and 3 are the same`. I don't see them the same.

Comment: They are the same with regard to ['num' , 'Ref' , 'Alt'], the 'DP' and 'NL' doesn't have to be the same. I need to drop the rows that are identical according to ['num' , 'Ref' , 'Alt']

Comment: Ah I see, you mean *across the 2 dataframes*, not within each dataframe.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's a bit confusing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate, then drop duplicates with `keep=False`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])\
       .drop_duplicates(subset=['num', 'Ref', 'Alt'], keep=False)

print(df)

   num Ref Alt    DP    NL
1  500   C   A  45.0  90.0
2  255   A   C  69.0  26.0
1  500   A   A  45.0  54.0
2  255   A   A  55.0  55.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code snippet gives you the required output:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([{"num": 300, "Ref": "C", "Alt": "A", "DP": 50.0, "NL": 30.0},
                    {"num": 500, "Ref": "C", "Alt": "A", "DP": 45.0, "NL": 90.0},
                    {"num": 255, "Ref": "A", "Alt": "C", "DP": 69.0, "NL": 26.0},
                    {"num": 450, "Ref": "B", "Alt": "B", "DP": 55.0, "NL": 25.0}])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([{"num": 300, "Ref": "C", "Alt": "A", "DP": 71.0, "NL": 88.0},
                    {"num": 500, "Ref": "A", "Alt": "A", "DP": 45.0, "NL": 54.0},
                    {"num": 255, "Ref": "A", "Alt": "A", "DP": 55.0, "NL": 55.0},
                    {"num": 450, "Ref": "B", "Alt": "B", "DP": 70.0, "NL": 15.0},])

print(df2[~df2.isin(df1)[["num", "Ref", "Alt"]].all(1)])
```

output:

```
  Alt    DP    NL Ref  num
1   A  45.0  54.0   A  500
2   A  55.0  55.0   A  255


print(df1[~df1.isin(df2)[["num", "Ref", "Alt"]].all(1)])
```

output:

```
  Alt    DP    NL Ref  num
1   A  45.0  90.0   C  500
2   C  69.0  26.0   A  255
```

If you want the output in a single dataframe. You can concatenate the dataframes and remove duplicate rows based on specific columns.